# How to use express type definition as parameter signature in plain JS project in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, types, visual-studio-code

I'm working on super simple express app with plain js. I use vscode as code editor. Here's my sample code for request handling.

```
class Product {
  /**
   * @param {Express.Request} request
   * @param {Express.Response} response
   */
  list(request, response) {
    request.par // <-- i want intellisense works, so it suggests method or property that match 'par'
  }
}
```

I want when I put jsdoc with express type definition, the intellisense would work, so it suggest what is available. Anybody know, how to get vscode intellisense works?

Comment: I don't think this questions belongs to StackOverflow since it's not _really_ code related.

Comment: This question perfectly valid. It is about coding and editor support while coding.
@Ibnu Madini How do you import `express` in this file?